# InitializingBean callback not fired when using autowireBeanProperties(this...)

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, autowired

In all our applications integration tests, we are using manual autowiring with the following:

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(getConfigLocations());
context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(this, getAutowireMode(), true);
```

This way, the required Spring beans are automatically injected in the test class (this).

This works fine, but in one of my test class, i've made my class being a InitializingBean.
When i autowire this way in my bean, the `afterPropertiesSet()` method is never triggered, while in debug i see all the properties being set correctly.

Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autowireBeanProperties()` only autowires properties, it doesn't perform other steps of initialization.

You can use other methods of [`AutowireCapableBeanFactory`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html) to perform the full initialization, such as `initializeBean()`. However, it looks like you cannot pass  `autowireMode` in this case. So, it's not clear how to solve this problem if you really need custom `autowireMode`s (i.e. if you don't use `@Autowired` in your bean).

Comment: thanks. I think i'll call the method myself after the autowiring it will be easier :)